# convert python3.2 game into exe with cx_Freeeze

Tags: python, pygame, exe, cx-freeze, python-3.2

**I have a problem about converting python3.2 game into exe with cx_Freeeze.**

Actually I have successfully "converted a game" to an exe with cx_Freeze, but it doesn't work at all, it can't be played. Some warning information was shown when I double-click the exe file.

The converting process works, because I have tried to convert some simple programmes into exe and it works.

But the one I want to convert is a "game", so it includes some dynamic import like importing pictures, `"dotImage = pygame.image.load('orange_dot.png')"`, something like that.

I don't know how to configure cx_Freeze Setup file to include these pictures and songs.

This is my Cx_Freeze Converting File

```
import os
import sys
if len(sys.argv)>1:
    None
else:
    File = input("Which script do you want to compile:")
    os.system("D:\Python32\Scripts\cxfreeze"+File)
    print("finish")
```

Or did I just missed something?

I am so confused about how to convert a "Python game" (with 3.2 version or higher) into exe.

Can anyone help me?

One more thing, I have added

```
import re
includes = ["re"]
import pygame._view
```

these three lines in my game, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write [`setup()][1]`, like you would do with `setup()` of `disutils`.

I think below would be a cx_Freeze setup boilerplate you can edit to meet your needs!

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = "Win32GUI" if sys.platform == "win32" else None
options={'base': base,
    'copy_dependent_files': True,
    'include_files': [ <files-to-include> ]
    'packages' : [ <dependant-packages> ],
    'excludes' : [ <packages-to-exclude> ],
}

setup(name = <name>
    version = <version>
    description = <description>
    options = {"build_exe" : options},
    executables = [Executable(script="script_name.py",
                              base = base,
                              targetName="script_name.exe",
                             )]

#usage : > python setup.by build_exe
```